# RuntimeError: Input type and weight type should be the same

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I’m trying to swap resNet blocks with resNext blocks in my current model. All worked and I even trained the model for 1000+ epochs with the resNet blocks but when I added the following class to the model, it returned this error. (ran without errors in my local CPU but got the error when running in colab)

**Added Class :**

```
class GroupConv1D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding, stride, groups):
    super(GroupConv1D, self).__init__()

    if not in_channels % groups == 0:
        raise ValueError("The input channels must be divisible by the no. of groups")
    if not out_channels % groups == 0:
        raise ValueError("The output channels must be divisible by the no. of groups")

    self.kernel_size = kernel_size
    self.stride = stride
    self.padding = padding
    self.groups = groups

    self.group_in_num = in_channels // groups
    self.group_out_num = out_channels // groups
    self.conv_list = []

    for i in range(self.groups):
        self.conv_list.append(
            nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=self.group_out_num,
                out_channels=self.group_out_num,
                kernel_size=kernel_size,
                stride=stride,
                padding=padding)
        )

def forward(self, inputs):
    feature_map_list = []
    for i in range(self.groups):
        x_i = self.conv_list[i](
            inputs[:, i * self.group_in_num: (i + 1) * self.group_in_num]
        )
        feature_map_list.append(x_i)

    out = torch.concat(feature_map_list, dim=1)
    return out
```

**The Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYPprototypeTest2/train.py", line 268, in <module>
  cycleGAN.trainModel()
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYPprototypeTest2/train.py", line 140, in trainModel
  B_fake = self.A_generator_B(A_real, A_mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in 
_call_impl
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYPprototypeTest2/model.py", line 235, in forward
  resnet_block_1 = self.resnet_block_1(conv2d_conv1d)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in 
_call_impl
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYPprototypeTest2/model.py", line 88, in forward
  group_layer = self.groupConv_1(layer_one_GLU)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in 
_call_impl
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 141, in 
forward
  input = module(input)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in 
_call_impl
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYPprototypeTest2/model.py", line 46, in forward
  inputs[:, i * self.group_in_num: (i + 1) * self.group_in_num]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in 
_call_impl
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 301, in forward
  return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 298, in 
_conv_forward
  self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should 
be the same
```

Help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You're casting your inputs to the GPU but your model isn't working on your CPU. Make sure you run `model.to(device)` prior to your training or inference, where `device` is your cuda GPU ordinal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Im actually running all my models using the relevant device (e.g - self.A_generator_B = Generator().to(self.device) ) and this is why everything works fine with my CPU. Also, everything worked fine with GPU as well before I added the above class. I strongly believe that the issue is within that class itself. I think there's something in that class that has the default device as the CPU but I couldn't spot the exact line.

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant code, demonstrating how you create your model and insert the above class.

Comment: You'll be able to find and recreate the error by running the model here : [link](https://github.com/Pasinduekanayake/testingModel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem in your new class `GroupConv1D` is that you store all your convolution modules in a *regular* python list `self.conv_list` instead of using [`nn` Containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers).
All methods that affect `nn.Module`s (e.g., `.to(device)`, `.eval()`, etc.) are applied recursively to all *relevant* members of the "root" `nn.Module`.
However, how can pytorch tell which are the *relevant* members?
For this you have [containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers): they group together sub-modules, registers and parameters such that pytorch can recursively apply all relevant `nn.Module`'s methods to them.

See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372348/1714410).