# Pytorch : Expected all tensors on same device

Tags: pytorch

I have my model and inputs moved on the same device but I still get the runtime error :

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)
```

Here is my code,
First my model implementation :

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_hiddens, n_feature= 2, n_output= 1):
        super().__init__()
        self.hiddens = []
        n_hidden_in = n_feature
        for n_hidden in n_hiddens :
          self.hiddens.append( torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_in, n_hidden) )   # hidden layer
          n_hidden_in = n_hidden

        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)   # output layer

    def forward(self, x):
        for hidden in self.hiddens :
          x = F.relu(hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
        x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
        return x
```

Then I define my dataloaders. Here, X and y are numpy arrays

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
# Split training/test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state= 42)

X_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_train)
y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(y_train)

X_test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_test)
y_test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(y_test)


train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor) # create your datset
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size= 1000) # create your dataloader

test_dataset = TensorDataset(X_test_tensor, y_test_tensor) # create your datset
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size= 1000) # create your dataloader
```

Here I train my model. The error occurs during the line "outputs = regressor(inputs)"

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 2000
BATCH_SIZE =  1000
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(f"Device used : {device}")

# 1 hidden layer
total_num_nodes = 256
regressor = Net(n_hiddens= [total_num_nodes]).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(regressor.parameters(), lr=0.2, momentum= 0.1, nesterov= True)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # this is for regression mean squared loss


for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  running_loss = 0.0

  for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader, 0):
    inputs, values = data
    inputs = inputs.float().to(device)
    values = values.float().to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()   # clear gradients for next train
    print(f"Input device is : cuda:{inputs.get_device()}")
    print(f"Target value device is : cuda:{values.get_device()}")
    print(f"Is model on cuda ? : {next(regressor.parameters()).is_cuda}")
    outputs = regressor(inputs) # <-- This is where I have the error
    loss = loss_func(outputs, values)
    loss.backward()         # backpropagation, compute gradients
    optimizer.step()        # apply gradients
```

Here are the outputs of my print statements :

```
Device used : cuda:0
Input device is : cuda:0
Target value device is : cuda:0
Is model on cuda ? :True
```

This should mean that my model and my tensors are all on the same device so why do I still have this error ?

The error log is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5234b830bebc> in <module>()
     24       print(f"Target value device is : cuda:{values.get_device()}")
     25       print(f"Is model on cuda ? : {next(regressor.parameters()).is_cuda}")
---> 26       outputs = regressor(inputs)
     27       loss = loss_func(outputs, values)
     28       loss.backward()         # backpropagation, compute gradients

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-4-56c54b30b771> in forward(self, x)
     16     def forward(self, x):
     17         for hidden in self.hiddens :
---> 18           x = F.relu(hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
     19         x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
     20         return x

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    101 
    102     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    104 
    105     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 
   1850 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: If you can please share the error log to see in which line the error popped up?

Comment: The error happens when i define "outputs". More specifically when it calls the linear transformation during the forward pass. I will copy the exact error log asap when i come home

Comment: Indeed, don't forget to provide the full error stack trace whenever you post on SO. If you have a tensor inside your network that hasn't been registered properly, it won't get transferred on the device. So maybe providing the implementation of `Net` would be relevant here too.

Comment: The outputs of print functions are not clear. Could you please write something inside each print function?

Comment: Also you can rewrite them like that using device attribute please:  print("inputs tensor is on "+inputs.device)

Comment: You can print the model like that: print(regressor.device)

Comment: I've edited the question with the full code (model, dataloader, training) and with the error logs and better print statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**  use [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) instead of a pythonic one to store the hidden layers in `Net`.

All your hidden layers are stored in a simple pythonic list `self.hidden` in `Net`. When you move your model to GPU, using `.to(device)`, pytorch has no way to tell that all the elements of this pythonic list should also be moved to the same device.
however, if you make `self.hidden = nn.ModuleLis()`, pytorch now knows to treat all elements of this special list as `nn.Module`s and *recursively* move them to the same device as `Net`.

See these answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830100/1714410), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684415/1714410), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372348/1714410) for more details.

Comment: I have a question when he printed to check whether the model is on GPU, the output is that the model is indeed on GPU. I think the model including all its layers are on GPU. What do you think?

Comment: @Phoenix if you store sub-modules/parameters/buffers in regular python lists/dicts pytorch has no way of knowing your module has submodules it should check for their device. This is why it is so important to use [containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers) and to properly register parameters and buffers.

Comment: But you did not answer my question regarding output of print functions.

Comment: @Phoenix since your sub modules are not stored in a proper container pytorch does not know about them. They will _NOT_ be part of `regressor.parameters()` at all! therefore, when you checked `regressor.parameters()` you only saw the ones that are _directly_ associated with `Net` and they are on device. While all parameters of the hidden layers are not part of `regerssor.parameters()` at all.

Comment: @Phoenix see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678896/pytorch-valueerror-optimizer-got-an-empty-parameter-list?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I had this error as well, only with the transformers PyTorch Trainer class, not with native PyTorch, see [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:6 (device_ids\[0\]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556). Yet, the problem could be the same: that there is a class that saves the parameters and buffers of the fine-tuning model to another device than the device that has already those of the main model.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but a hint that may help those with errors like this.

I had this error as well, only with the transformers PyTorch Trainer class, not with native PyTorch, see [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:6 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556), which is also about

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found
> at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:4! (when checking argument for
> argument index in method wrapper_CUDA__index_select)

It just did not fit in that question header anymore.

In PyTorch Trainer and native PyTorch, the problem could be the same:

- that there is a class that saves the parameters and buffers of the one model (my fine-tuning model)
- to another device than the device that has already those parameters and buffers of the other model (the main model).

Or in your question, you save the one model on the CPU and the other on a GPU, which also does not work. You need to check `nvidia-smi` and see whether the GPU 0 memory grows during the steps.

On top of that, I had a mapping problem so that choosing for example GPU 6 in the code was GPU 4 in `nvidia-smi`. There is a quick answer to that, see ["model.to('cuda:6')" becomes (nvidia-smi) GPU 4, same with any other "cuda:MY_GPU", only "cuda:0" becomes GPU 0. How do I get rid of this mapping?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126490/97556). And there is a longer proof with code at [How to Solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841).

You can check where the main model and the fine-tuning model device gets saved (`nvidia-smi`) and then change the code so that both models get saved on the same device, like in the following, taken from [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:6 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556), where I changed the main device from `'cuda:6'` to `'cuda:0'` and GPU 6 to GPU 0:

```py
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='0,6,3,7,2'
...
torch.device('cuda:0')
...
device_ids = [0,6,3,7,2]
...
        model=model.to('cuda:0'), # "model=model" should run through as well
...
    model.to('cuda:0')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the model and the inputs not being moved to the same device before calling the model. To resolve, move both the model and inputs to the same device before running the model:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)
inputs = inputs.to(device)
```